# How do I write a doctest test case with a value template?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, doctest

In doctest, the C++ testing framework, we can write:

```
TEST_SUITE("foo") {

    TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE("bar", T, t1, t2, t3) {
        /* code using template parameter T */
    }

}
```

and this works - if `t1`, `t2`, `t3` are *types*. The way it's implemented is that doctest generates code including

```
template<typename T>
inline void DOCTEST_ANONYMOUS(_DOCTEST_ANON_TMP_)()
```

and invokes this function for the macro arguments after `T`. This obviously does not work for *value* arguments, e.g. `TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE("bar", MyType, v1, v2, v3)`.

Can we use doctest to create templates over numeric parameters?

Answer (score 2):

An ugly solution (not using any doctest facilities) would be:

```
template <typename T, T Value>
struct value_as_type { static constexpr const T value { Value }; };
```

and then replacing

```
TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE("bar", T, t1, t2, t3) { /*... etc ... */ }
```

with:

```
TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE("bar", MyType, 
    value_as_type<MyType, v1>,
    value_as_type<MyType, v2>,
    value_as_type<MyType, v3>)  
{
    constexpr const MyType val { MyType::value };
    /*... etc ... */
}
```